# create a function to return meters per second

Tags: python, function

I am terrible a math and am really struggling with this, any help would be appreciated: The answer is apparently 19.444

````
    meters = kmph * 10
    hour = 3600
    speed = (meters/hour) * 60
    return speed

ms(156)
26.0```
````

Comment: Are you sure the anwser is 19.444 I personnaly find 43.33 because you have to divide by 3.6 to pass from kmph to mps

Comment: long story short i think you are correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got this :

```
def kmph_to_ms(kmph):
    if kmph >= 0:
        return kmph/3.6
    else
        return 'Please enter a positive value.'
```

It should work fine